# DIV and tables - multiple rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to put a div inside of a table however, it will not go across multiple rows.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>row 2 stuff</td></td>
    </div>
</table>
```

I have multiple rows that are dynamically added on a button click.  I would like each group of dynamically added rows to be inside of a div for easy removal.

The problem is FireFox is automatically closing the div tag in the same cell.  At the very end, it is moving my closing  to the end of the first cell.

Answer (score 2):

Latest tag opened should be closed first to get the perfect result.
Your code should look somehow like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="test"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>row 2 stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your markup does not abide by html standards in the sense that you are imporperly nesting. If you want to add a row use the following formation

```
<table>
    <div id="test">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>row 2 stuff</td></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

If you notice, I grouped the two rows within one div. Even this is ill advised as you are nesting a div within a table. A more convenient solution would be to assign a class to the divs you want to group together like so:

```
<table>
    <tr class="test">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
       <td>row 2 stuff</td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here the rows I want to group together are assigned a common class. So if I were to select them with say Jquery, I would do :

```
$("tr.test")
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wrap a `<div>` tag around table elements like that. If you would like to keep an easy reference to each row, consider keeping references to all of the newly-added rows, or add a class to them for later access.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.  I will try assigning each row an ID and remove the group of them that way.

Comment: @KevinJohnson Just remember now to use the same `id` twice. If you use a class, you can assign the same class to all of the rows and them find them all easily for removal at a later time.

Comment: What @JonathanSampson is hinting at is, "getElementsByClassName()", developed by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com, which will permit one quick wipe and all will be gone. The issue with your tag order is known as 'chaining', which you now understand will not fly.

Answer (score 0):

Html tags must be strictly within another tag. The following markup is therefore not allowed:

```
<b>this <i>is a</b> test</i>
```

Your markup breaks the same rule.